# Greedy algorithm - Criteria for a coin system to be canonical

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, greedy

Given a coin system, what are the conditions that can be used to figure out whether the coin system is canonical. I did read a few papers but nothing solid came off from them.

I know that greedy algorithm works only for canonical coin systems. I am trying to figure out if the coins ={1, 2, 3, 6} is a canonical coin system. Can I know what is the criteria used to decide this?

Comment: To make 6 out of [1, 3, 4], the greedy algorithm will use 4+1+1 = 3 coins, where the optimal solution (minimum coins) would be 3 + 3 = 2 coins = not canonical.
Your example, [1, 2, 3, 6] seems to be canonical - I couldn't find an optimal solution with less coins than greedy algorithm's.
Make two functions: greedy and optimum, send both an amount, and see which returns less coins: if it's the optimum, then it's not canonical.

Comment: @iAmOren Counterintuitively, determining whether greedy produced the best answer for a given value turns out to be NP-hard.  But determining whether greedy produces the best answer for every value can be done in polynomial time.  The key is that the smallest counterexample by virtue of being smallest is simpler to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [https://graal.ens-lyon.fr/~abenoit/algo09/coins2.pdf](https://graal.ens-lyon.fr/%7Eabenoit/algo09/coins2.pdf) for a `O(n^3)` algorithm for answering whether a given set of coins is canonical.

Answer (score 0):

For your system, the best change for any amount:

- must use fewer than 2 1s, because otherwise you could use a 2 instead.
- must use fewer than 3 2s, because otherwise you could use a 6 instead.
- must use fewer than 2 3s, because otherwise you could use a 6 instead.

Furthermore, in the best change for any amount, the greedy algorithm will find all the 6s.  If there is an amount for which the greedy algorithm is wrong, therefore, then it must be wrong for just the amount formed by the other coins, after the 6s are removed.

There are only 2 * 3 * 2 = 12 combinations of those other coins in any best change, so just try them all:  [], [1], [2], [1,2], [2,2], [1,2,2], [3], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2,3], [2,2,3], [1,2,2,3].

The greedy algorithm wins in all of those cases, so your system is canonical.

You can make a similar calculation for any coin system.  It won't always be fast for for inputs that are completely unlike real coin systems.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured this one out. Here is how you determine if a set of coins are canonical:

1. Sort the coins from small to large
2. Go through all coins larger than one cent. If each coin can be changed using *immediately consecutive* smaller coins, the set is canonical.

We can look at it through some examples:

1. The US coin system [1, 5, 10, 25, 100] is canonical.
2. But if we add a coin of 12 cents to the mix, it's not canonical anymore. We can't change 12 with 10 and 5. We have to use 10 and 1. The result is greedy algorithm stops working. For example, to break down 15 cents, we shouldn't use 12 + 1 * 3; instead 10 + 5 is the best solution.
3. If we add 15 to the US coin system, it remains canonical, because 25 = 15 + 10 and 15 = 10 + 5. All coins can still be changed with immediately consecutive smaller coins.
4. If we add 2, it remains canonical: [1,2,5,10,25,100].
5. [1, 2, 5, 9, 19, 28, 84] is also canonical because all coins can be changed by using immediately consecutive coins:

- 84 = 28 * 3
- 28 = 19 + 9
- 19 = 9 + 5 * 2
- 9 = 5 + 2 * 2
- 5 = 2 * 2 + 1

This theory is probably not 100% correct, but I can't think of any counter examples. Comments are welcome!

Comment: think about 1,3,4 and 1,2,5