# Identifying when greedy method gives optimum solution

Tags: algorithm, greedy, minimization, coin-change

I was looking at this problem on leetcode

https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-number-of-operations-to-convert-time/description/

The hints tell us to follow a greedy approach where we convert the time difference to minutes and pick the largest possible values

For the given allowed values [1,5,15,60] greedy seems to work for all cases

**But let us assume a case where the difference b/w time is 46 minutes and the allowed values are [1,23,40] then as per greedy, the operation would take 7 steps but the minimum possible is 2 ( 23 + 23 )**

Why don't we have similar case for the values given the original problem ? how can it be proved that greedy is always the optimal solution in the case of the original problem ? and how can we know, for a given set of allowed values, do we get the optimal solution with greedy or not ?

Comment: This is a reformatting of the Change-Making Problem, under which the question of "For what denominations does the Greedy Method always work?" Is known as "Cannonical Coinsets".  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem#Greedy_method) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121896/what-property-of-a-coin-system-makes-it-canonical) for more information.

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63759434/109122

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121896/what-property-of-a-coin-system-makes-it-canonical

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very similar to the [coin change problem](https://www.interviewbit.com/blog/coin-change-problem/). In general you are very much correct and the greedy solution is not optimal. **However** is this case the greedy solution is optimal since the "coins" are complete multiplications of each other :

```
1 * 5 = 5
5 * 3 = 15
15 * 4 = 60
```

Since this is the case each `60` step can be done by 4 `15` steps or 12 `5` steps. Therefore the greedy solutions is best in this case.

In the second example you shoed, the "coins" were not a multiplication of each other, making the greedy solution sub-optimal in some cases.

Comment: Note that there are many coinsets that are canonical even when they are not complete multiplications of each other.  For instance `{2,3}` is a canonical coinset even though 3 is not a multiple of 3.  In general it takes `O(n^3)` to determine if a coinset is canonical or not.